# Drupal 7, programmatically add field_image to entity

Tags: drupal, file-upload, drupal-7, drupal-modules

In Drupal 7 I created an entity programmatically. It has a few textfields added like name, price etc in the form:

```
$form['data']['name'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('Name'),
   '#default_value' => isset($model->data['name']) ? $model->data['name']: '',
   '#maxlength' => 255,
   '#required' => TRUE,
   '#weight' => -3,
);
```

However, I'd like to be able to add multiple images to every entity it as well.

When I use Drupal's user interface to add fields, I can pick "Image: field_image (Image)" at the bottom, under "Add an existing field". This field has exactly the behaviour I want.

How can I add it programmatically to my entity?

Answer (score 0):

You can just extend the content-type you made with the Drupal UI by using the `HOOK_form_alter()`-hook.

Or you can find out what the Array is generating when you make a multiple image-field by using a `var_dump();` and add it to the Array of your custom made template.

Comment: Are you suggesting I output the $form variable at the end of my `hook_edit_form()` and then implementing it by hand in a `$form['data']['images'] = array()`? This doesn't seem like a good idea as each uploaded file is added at the beginning of the array. Or am I missing something obvious here?